# What do you call a function $f$ such that $f(f(x))=x$?

Tags: functions

What is the name of the property of a function that yields the original result when done twice in a row:

$$f(f(x)) = x?$$

I'm pretty sure there is a word for these functions, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: The are often called involutions (which generally means something that squares to the identity).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function that has this property is known as an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)).

Such functions are interesting to study, as they are their own inverse
$$f^{-1}(x) = f(x)$$

Some examples:$$f(x) = x\\f(x) = \frac{a}{x}\\f(x) = a - x\\f(x) = a + \frac{b}{x-a}$$

Comment: Further examples in $\Bbb R^n$ can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.